# CreateFile returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE for two same device paths

Tags: c++, winapi, device

I'm making application that listens for device notifications(through `WndProc`, `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` and `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL`). When I process `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` in `WndProc`, I get device path from `PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE` structure. When I try to create device handle with that path, it succeeds.

```
HANDLE device_handle = CreateFile(device_path.c_str(),
        GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (device_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;
```

But when I handle `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE`, I do the same thing with `PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE` structure, and the path is same as in `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL`, but `CreateFile` always returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`

The funniest thing is, when I try to execute in debug mode, creating device handle works normally, both from `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` and `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE`.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Doesn't the `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` event imply that the device has been removed? If so I would expect an attempt to open the device that is no more to fail.

Comment: when `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` come - device already removed and name not valid. so must be error file not found

Comment: Thanks ! 
But is there a way to intercept removal and to get device path before device is removed ?

Comment: for what ? for what you need open device on removal, when device destroyed ?

Comment: I need to notify users which device has been removed

Comment: Are you trying to open the device to get a human-friendly device description? If so, asking for that would probably make for a more valuable question.

Comment: @someguy Can't you get that info from `DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE` or `DBT_DEVICEREMOVEPENDING`? Why do you need to wait until the device has been completely removed from the system before getting its info?

Comment: @IInspectable yes, with device handle, i'm reading stuff like pid,vid,manufacturer etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried with both, but none of those are selected in switch statement in WndProc

Comment: @someguy that is a different issue entirely. Please [edit] your question to show the actual `WndProc` code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

It is improper to create handle when receiving `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` message.

> The system broadcasts the [`DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/dbt-deviceremovecomplete) device
> event when a device or piece of media has been physically removed.

You can use [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerdevicenotificationw) to receive more specific device event messages. There is a [MSDN:sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/processing-a-request-to-remove-a-device).